# How to correctly link the cppgit2 library

Tags: c++, cmake

Im trying for two days now to get cppgit2 working and I can not figure out how to do it.
I have build it using cmake and make and am now trying to run one of the given examples.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cppgit2/repository.hpp>

int main() {
    auto repo = cppgit2::repository::open("/home/[...]");

    repo.for_each_commit([](const cppgit2::commit &c) {
        std::cout << c.id().to_hex_string(8) << " [" << c.committer().name()
                  << "]"
                  << " " << c.summary() << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

When I know try to run my code, I get this error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/maya_git_integration.dir/src/git.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'git_libgit2_shutdown'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/[...]/lib/cppgit2/build/lib/git2.so.1.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/maya_git_integration.dir/build.make:125: maya_git_integration] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/maya_git_integration.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/maya_git_integration.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:138: maya_git_integration] Error 2
```

The funny part is, that a simpler example like

```cpp
#include <cppgit2/repository.hpp>
using namespace cppgit2;

int main() {
  auto repo = repository::init("hello_world", false);
}
```

Runs perfectly.
When I understand the error correctly, I should add something like `-lcppgit2` to the program arguments. I tried that using the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lcppgit2 -lgit2")`, but that just threw warnings and `Can not find -lcppgit2`.
Thats the complete cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(cppgit2_error_solving)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -lcppgit2 -lgit2")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("lib/cppgit2/build/include")
add_executable(cppgit2_error_solving main.cpp)
find_library(CPPGIT2_LIBRARY cppgit2 HINTS ./lib/cppgit2/build/lib)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cppgit2_error_solving ${CPPGIT2_LIBRARY})
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET cppgit2_error_solving PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

Its basically copied from the readme of the cppgit2 repo.
So if someone could tell me where to add what program argument to run this code I would be very happy.
Thanks for you time!

Comment: The approach with `find_library` and `target_link_libraries` should work. Use it for both `cppgit2` and `git2` libraries (since you need to link with both these libraries). The variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` is a wrong place for `-l` options: these options are for the **linker**, not for the *compiler*.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick.

Comment: Please note, that on Stack Overflow we don't edit question post for include "solved" mark. Once an answer to the question will be accepted, the question will be automatically marked green. Moreover, having accepted answer doesn't prevent other answers to be created: Stack Overflow is the collection of question/answers which are **useful for future**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody that might have this problem in the future:
As pointed out by Tsyvarev in the comments, both the cppgit2 **AND** the git2 library have to be added to the cmake like so

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cppgit2_error_solving ${CPPGIT2_LIBRARY} git2)
```

That solved it for me.